# SQL server extension not working in PHP v7.4.8

Tags: php, iis

So I was updating our web servers (Windows 2012 R2/IIS) with the newest version of PHP this morning (version 7.4.8 from 7.4.6, because I was slacking 2 weeks ago).

In our setup, we include the dll from Microsoft (php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts.dll) in the ext folder as we have some sites running some PDO lookups to some backend SQL servers.  After I registered the new version, I started getting errors in those PDO calls (PDO is loading), but I'm getting cannot find driver.  As soon as I switch back over to 7.4.6, everything loads.

I didn't see a newer file provided from Microsoft yet.  Is anyone else seeing this behavior or have a fix for it yet?

Thanks,

Comment: I would expect a Windows system to use the Thread Safe version of a dll?

Comment: Where did you get a version 7.4.8 from? The latest available on the PHP home page is 7.4.7.

Comment: https://windows.php.net/download/, current version is 7.4.8 released on 7/7/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was eventually fixed in the release of 7.4.10.  It was a little known error it seems, but they got it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Since I had more then one php version installation.I had to specify the specific extension folder in my php7.4.8 ini file.  i.e.extension_dir = "C:/php7.4/ext"

Everything worked fine after that

Comment: I always define it with the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Since there could be multiple PHP version side-by-side.

1.Please ensure your IIS PHP-CGI handler is pointing to the right version.

2.Please ensure you have copy the dll to the right ext folder

3.Please ensure you have set the correct extension_dir

4.Please ensure you have registered the extension=..... correctly.

5.Please do an IISRESET when you finish updating the configuration.

You can try to double click php-cgi.exe to check the real exception. If everything is set correctly, there might be some compatibility issue.

Comment: Everything is pointed in the right direction and registered correctly.  Good list to go through.  I did test this morning, and everything works correctly in version 7.4.7, so something changed in 7.4.8 that is causing some issue.

Comment: Have you tried to double click php-cgi.exe to check the real exception? If there is a issue, there should be an error message. Have you encountered any error message?

Answer (score 0):

> Have you tried to double click php-cgi.exe to check the real
> exception? If there is a issue, there should be an error message. Have
> you encountered any error message?

No error after double clicking php-cgi.exe

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of this, but I'm finding something that makes just as little sense.  The error I'm receiving is 
The procedure entry point zval_ptr_dtor could not be located in the dynamic link library php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts.dll